# Do alchemists/investigators with swift alchemy take less time to make extracts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, alchemy, alchemist

Are extracts considered alchemical items for the purposes of swift alchemy?

And what about mutagens and bombs?

Do this items benefit from the halved creation time?

Comment: Bombs don't have any "creation time" other than the daily limit and the standard action to throw them. Preparing them is considered a part of resting, just as a cleric praying for his spells or a Wizard studying his spellbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Alchemical Items are a specifically defined class of items that require a Craft (Alchemy) check to create. Examples include Alchemist's Fire, Acid, Poisons, Smelling Salts, Smokesticks, etc. Further examples can be found [here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/alchemicalWeapons.html), [here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/alchemicalRemedies.html), and [here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/alchemicalTools.html)

Potions are considered Magic Items, and Extracts, Bombs, and Mutagens are all class features that don't require a skill check. Thus, Swift Alchemy doesn't apply to any of them.